# Can't get my preg_match working

Tags: php, regex

I just keep trying different combinations with preg_match or preg_match_all, but I'm plainly confused.
Here's the code line that I use :

```
preg_match ("/(?<=(\[".$tag."\]))(.+)(?=(\[\/".$tag."\]))/s", $text, $matches);
```

(a look-behind and look-ahead to match the text within tags : [tag] (.+) [/tag]

The subject is a variable that contains text like this :

```
[title]Hi this is my title[/title]
[text]some text[/text]
[hidden]some hidden text[/hidden]
[text]again some more text[/text]
[end]end[/end]
```

Now I'm trying to display only the different parts of text within [text][/text]
So I would like my echo to display :

```
some text
again some more text
```

However when I try to echo my $matches (array), the best I could get is :

```
some text[/text]
[hidden]some hidden text[/hidden]
[text]again some more text
```

It considers only the first and last tag. I've tried other combinations of parameters, but I just get errors regarding the offset, etc.

What should I do ?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

**Incorporate** this simplified regex instead. `/\['.$tag.'](.*?)\[\/'.$tag.']/`

```
 <?php
 $tag = 'text';  //<--------- Pass the tag name (you can even add title , hidden )
    $str='[title]Hi this is my title[/title]
    [text]some text[/text]
    [hidden]some hidden text[/hidden]
    [text]again some more text[/text]
    [end]end[/end]';

    preg_match_all('/\['.$tag.'](.*?)\[\/'.$tag.']/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/133713)

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => some text
    [1] => again some more text
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of greedy quantifiers: By default, the `+` tries to take as much as it can. If you don't want that, add a `?` after the quantifier to make it non-greedy:

```
preg_match ("/(?<=([".$tag."]))(.+?)(?=([/".$tag."]))/s", $text, $matches);
```

This way, the dot will try to match the smallest amount of characters possible.

As Shankar Damodaran pointed out, there's no need for lookaheads and lookbehinds here, so you might as well write:

```
preg_match ("/\[".$tag."](.+?)(\[\/".$tag."]/s", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Ooooh that's what "greedy" means in the php help.
Took me 30 min to figure out I just was missing one character. damn regexes, thanks a lot !

Comment: You might also want to incorporate Shankar Damodaran's adjustment, which gets rid of the unnecessary lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`preg_matchall`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$input_lines='[title]Hi this is my title[/title]
[text]some text[/text]
[hidden]some hidden text[/hidden]
[text]again some more text[/text]
[end]end[/end]';

preg_match_all("/(?<=\[text\])(.*)(?=\[\/text\])/", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array[0]);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some text
    [1] => again some more text
)
```